# Find a set that spans the set of all 3 by 3 semimagic matrices and prove it

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Call a 3 × 3 matrix a semi-magic square if all its rows and columns (but not necessarily its diagonals) have the same sum.

The questions asks me to find a set that spans the set of all 3 by 3 semimagic matrices and prove it

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623551/dimension-of-vector-space-of-matrices-with-zero-row-and-column-sum) might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In   order    to answer the question we have to cope with two issues

- *Semimagic matrices*: We need a proper characterisation of these specific matrices.
- *Linear span*: Once we have a candidate for the set of *all* semimagic matrices, we have to show this set is a *[linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span)*, which means a subspace in the vector space of all $\mathcal{M}_{(3\times 3)}$ matrices with the usual addition and scalar multiplication over a field $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ (resp. $\mathbb{C}$).

> **Semimagic matrices:**
>
> Let's assume a semimagic $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ has a column-sum, resp. row-sum equal to $n_A$. Whenever we consider two elements $x,y$ in a column or row  of $A$ the third element is determined by
>   \begin{align*}
> n_A-x-y\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   It follows the shape of a semimagic matrix $A$ is necessarily
>   \begin{align*}
> A=\begin{pmatrix}
> a&b&n_A-a-b\\
> c&d&n_A-c-d\\
> n_A-a-c&n_A-b-d&a+b+c+d-n_A
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{align*}
>   with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{F}$ arbitrarily, fixed. Note, the element $a_{3,3}$ of $A$ is according to (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> a_{3,3}=n_A-(n_A-a-b)-(n_A-c-d)=a+b+c+d-n_A
> \end{align*}

We conclude, the set of *all* semimagic $3\times 3$ matrices $\mathcal{S}$ is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{S}=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&n_A-a-b\\
c&d&n_A-c-d\\
n_A-a-c&n_A-b-d&a+b+c+d-n_A
\end{pmatrix}
\right|a,b,c,d,n_A\in\mathbb{F}
\right\}
\end{align*}

Note that we have *five* degrees of freedom: $a,b,c,d$ *and* $n_A$.

> **Linear span:**
>
> The set $\mathcal{S}$ is a perfect candidate for the linear span we are looking for. We see the zero matrix
>   \begin{align*}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0\\
> \end{pmatrix}\in \mathcal{S}
> \end{align*}
>   which is the zero vector of the vector space $\mathcal{M}_{(3\times 3)}$ is an element of $\mathcal{S}$.
>
> Let $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{F}$ and $A,B\in \mathcal{S}$ arbitrarily, fixed. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \lambda A + \mu B &=\lambda
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&n_A-a_{1,1}-a_{1,2}\\
> a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&n_A-a_{2,1}-a_{2,2}\\
> n_A-a_{1,1}-a_{2,1}&n_A-a_{1,2}-a_{2,2}&a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+a_{2,1}+a_{2,2}-n_A\\
> \end{pmatrix}\\
> &\qquad\quad+\mu
> \begin{pmatrix}
> b_{1,1}&b_{1,2}&n_B-b_{1,1}-b_{1,2}\\
> b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}&n_B-b_{2,1}-b_{2,2}\\
> n_B-b_{1,1}-b_{2,1}&n_B-b_{1,2}-b_{2,2}&b_{1,1}+b_{1,2}+b_{2,1}+b_{2,2}-n_B\\
> \end{pmatrix}\\
> &=\begin{pmatrix}
> c_{1,1}&c_{1,2}&n_C-c_{1,1}-c_{1,2}\\
> c_{2,1}&c_{2,2}&n_C-c_{2,1}-c_{2,2}\\
> n_C-c_{1,1}-c_{2,1}&n_C-c_{1,2}-c_{2,2}&c_{1,1}+c_{1,2}+c_{2,1}+c_{2,2}-n_C\\
> \end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{S}\\
> \end{align*}
>   with $n_C=\lambda n_A+\mu n_B$ and the claim follows.

Comment: @user148269: Thanks  for   granting the  bounty!  Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**

If $S$ is semimagic, with row and column sum $N$, and
$$
S
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & ?\\
c & d & ?\\
? & ? & ?\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
what can you say of the missing entries?

---

**Hint 2**
$$
S
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & N-a-b\\
c & d & ?\\
? & ? & ?\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: The remaining entries are either 0 or one of a,b,c,d?

Comment: @user148269, I have added a second hint.