# Let $V$ be the vector space of all $4$x$4$ matrices such that the sum of the elements in any row or any column is the same.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Let $V$ be the vector space of all $4$x$4$ matrices such that the sum of the elements in any row or any column is the same. What is the dimension of $V$?

Sol: I thought of this matrix where every row and column sums to $s$ and since it has $10$ variables I think the dim is 10. By separating and taking out the variables I could come up with a $10$ element basis. Through an obvious but lengthy process I could show its linear independence and the fact that it's a spanning set is obvious from the construction. Is this correct?
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & s-(a+b+c)\\ 
d & e & f & s-(d+e+f)\\ 
g & h & i & s-(g+h+i)\\ 
s-(a+d+g) & s-(b+e+h) & s-(c+f+i) &-2s+(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: $10$-D makes sense to me

Comment: @gt6989b Is there a faster way to do this that doesn't involve finding a particular basis?

Comment: The upper $3 \times 3$ corner and any one other cell can be considered a $10$-coordinate vector in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ with independent dimensions, so $\dim V \ge 10$. To prove $\dim V \le 10$ you observe any other entry is a linear combination of the 10 independent entries. Not sure there is a faster way

Comment: If you find an injective map from $\mathbb{K}^{10}$ to your vector space, and show it is surjective (eg. sending the standard basis onto your basis), it could be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the dimension of the subspace of $M_n(K)$ with equal row and column sum is $(n-1)^2+1$, see here:

[Dimension of vector space of matrices with zero row and column sum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623551/dimension-of-vector-space-of-matrices-with-zero-row-and-column-sum)

Actually, if the value is supposed to be zero, the dimension is $(n-1)^2$. This follows for $m=n$ from the duplicate. We have to add plus $1$, if the value is not prescribed.

Answer (score 2):

You were definitely on the right track, but maybe identifying a clear basis of size $10$ for the Vector Space would confidently help you say that the dimension is indeed $10$.

---

Notice that in your matrix construction above, the $3\times3$ submatrix given by: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

has the interesting property that all the $9$ elements are free to take any value **because we can always choose the $4th$ element of each row/column such that the sum across the row/column still becomes $S$.**

This also makes clear that these $9$ elements have a huge role to play, since the remaining elements are adjusted as per the values that these $9$ elements take.

---

If the condition were that $S=0$ (i.e. all the rows/columns have a sum of $0$), then keeping in mind the point made above, basis members for a Vector Space of $4\times4 $ matrices with each row/column sum equal to zero are easily given by:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&-1\\
-1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&-1&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, these $9$ matrices are very clearly linearly independent. Also, any $4\times4$ matrix with each row/column sum equal to zero can be given by a Linear Combination of these $9$ matrices.

For example if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&\alpha_1\\
d&e&f&\alpha_2\\
g&e&h&\alpha_3\\
\alpha_4&\alpha_5&\alpha_6&\alpha_7\\
\end{bmatrix}$ is one such matrix, then $$A=a\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}+\cdots+h\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

(I encourage you to actually construct a $4\times4$ matrix and verify that this works.)

---

Finally, we arrive at the last and simple bit of our task. **What if $S\neq0$?**
If you have been able to keep up so far, I think this should strike you as a little obvious. The small change here is to include $\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ in our existing basis of size $9$.

For example if we consider $B=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&\alpha_1\\
d&e&f&\alpha_2\\
g&e&h&\alpha_3\\
\alpha_4&\alpha_5&\alpha_6&\alpha_7\\
\end{bmatrix}$ to be a matrix with each row/column sum equal to $S$ (not necessarily equal to $0$), then

$$B=a\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}+\cdots+h\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&-1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}+S\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

(I again encourage you to construct a $4\times4$ matrix and check the validity of the result)

---

Hence, we can now confidently say that we have obtained a basis of size $10$ and the dimension of the vector space of all $4\times4$ matrices such that the sum of the elements in any row or any column is the same **must be $10$**.